# Эксплуатация и применение

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов

Здравствуйте, уважаемые филологи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, ответ на следующий вопрос.
В русском языке имеется термин, пришедший из французского языка: "**эксплуатация**".
 Можно ли сказать, что термин  "**назначение**" (врачом), а также термин "**применение**" (врачом и/или пациентом) лекарственного препарата являются именно **эксплуатацией лекарственного препарата**?
Если да/нет, то почему? Желательно аргументированно. Большое спасибо

Comment: Основное значение этого термина:  Извлечение выгоды, прибыли из кого-чего-н., присвоение чужого труда (социол. полит.). 2. Использование для каких-н. практических целей земли, промышленных предприятий, транспорта и т. д.

Comment: Т. е. ни о какой эксплуатации лекарственного препарата не может идти речи. Однако  Niemand прав: это юридический вопрос, поэтому лучше обратиться к юристам, а потом, если нужно, провести лингвистическую экспертизу.

Comment: В суде "заявление: Это мнение филологов", вам не поможет. Нужен официальный орган. К кому они могут прислушаться.

Comment: Эксплуатировать можно здание больницы, склад медикаментов и медицинскую технику (напр. рентгеновский аппарат), но не расходные материалы (лекарства или фотоматериалы для рентг. снимков), которые при использовании по назначению прекращают своё существование в исходном виде. Точно так же эксплуатируют месторождение угля, но никак не сам уголь.

Answer (score 1):

**Происхождение.** Слово "эксплуатация" восходит к лат. **explicare** – разворачивать, развивать от приставки экс-(из-) и глагола plicare – складывать или плести.

**История.** В западноевропейских языках имело значение "**добывать, практически использовать**" (природные ископаемые, машины, железные дороги и т.д.). На Западе политический смысл (**получать прибыль, эксплуатировать чужой труд**)  слово приобрело только  в 40-х годах 19 века. В России оно известно с середины 19 века, причем у Даля это слово имеет значение  "извлечение из чего-то промышленных выгод" и дается с пометкой "слово довольно неуклюжее".

**В современных словарях:**

ЭКСПЛУАТИРОВАТЬ,   2) кого. **Вынуждать кого-л. много работать на кабальных условиях или вообще безвозмездно (обычно извлекая для себя пользу, выгоду**). Э. всех производителей. Э. творческих работников. Начальник его бессовестно эксплуатирует. // Разг. Заставлять кого-л. много трудиться, делать что-л. не для себя, жертвуя своими интересами. Э. родителей, жену. // **Ловко пользоваться чем-л., извлекая для себя какую-л. выгоду, пользу.** Э. чужие достижения. Э. опубликованные научные труды. Он эксплуатирует её слабости. Коллектив эксплуатировал его любовь к общественной работе.

4) **Использовать по назначению орудия и средства производства, механизмы и т.п., а также сооружения, здания, территории** и т.п. Э. оборудование. Э. мост в течение столетия. Э. горы для научных исследований. Э. пляжи как зону отдыха.

**Вывод.**

1) Таким образом,  глагол "эксплуатировать" – это не синоним глагола "использовать", он имеет частное (узкое) значение и относится **к средствам производства, а не к производимой с их помощью продукции.**

2) С другой стороны, **речь может идти об использовании чего-либо в своих корыстных целях, а эта тема уже ближе к лекарствам  и их применению.**

Answer (score 0):

Если вы, съедая бутерброд, эксплуатируете его, то, пожалуй,  и применение лекарства можно считать эксплуатацией.

Аргументированно?

Comment: Я тоже придерживаюсь такой точки зрения, но хотелось бы именно научного объяснения. Мне, как врачу, нужно дать пояснения в суде, где государственный орган считает применение и назначение препарата эксплуатацией, а больница утверждает примерно как Вы. Но суду- то так не заявить (относительно бутерброда), поэтому и прошу совета у филологов, дабы обосновать исходя из значения слов

Comment: @Николай, с государственным органом спорить трудно, даже толковые словари вряд ли помогут. Вопрос, наверно, больше юридический: как принято считать, так и считают. По секрету могу сказать, что филологов здесь не слишком много, в основном любители.

Answer (score 0):

Логично предположить, что врач может *назначать* (или *выписывать*) лекарственный препарат. *Применять* (*использовать*) препарат по назначению (в соответствии с предписанными: курсом и дозировкой) может – пациент или младший медперсонал, если делать это самостоятельно пациенту невозможно (уколы), а *принимать* – только пациент.

*Эксплуатировать* (содержать в пригодном состоянии) можно было бы медицинское *оборудование*, однако ФЕДЕРАЛЬНЫЙ ЗАКОН от 21.11.2011 N 323-ФЗ "ОБ ОСНОВАХ ОХРАНЫ ЗДОРОВЬЯ ГРАЖДАН В РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ", даже в этом случае, такими терминами не оперирует. В этом документе есть статья «госконтроль за *обращением* медицинских *изделий*». Из контекста ясно, что термин «обращение» используется вместо слова «эксплуатация», а термин «изделие» включает в себя и понятие «оборудование».

В спорных ситуациях, свое мнение следует обосновывать ссылками на статьи, положения, (требования) действующих законов, приказов, актов (стандартов). При таком подходе проигрывает тот, кому не на что  сослаться, кроме собственного мнения, изложенного с применением сомнительной (несуществующей) терминологии.